# Is there way to simplify this code too many if else statment

Tags: php, ajax, if-statement, switch-statement

The Code supposed to rate user input and get the correct answer for the User. it works alright but just want to minimize it may be implment it in MVC.
am getting the variables from Ajax post.
Need Your Help if is possible Thanx a lot.

```
<?php
    function getResults($type) {

        // variables to store Ajax post Data.
        $period = $_POST ['duration'];
        $place = $_POST ['vacationplace'];
        $serv = $_POST ['services'];
        $disc = $_POST ['discovery'];
        $Trans = $_POST ['transport'];
        $accomp = $_POST ['accompanied'];
        $stars = $_POST ['stars'];

        // Results Array
        $type = array (
                0 => array (
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Weltenbummler" 
                ),

                1 => array (

                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Luxusliebhaber" 
                ),
                2 => array (
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Naturbursche/-madle" 
                ),
                3 => array (
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Sunnyboy/-girl" 
                ),
                4 => array (
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Wasserratte" 
                ),
                5 => array (
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Wellnessliebhaber" 
                ),
                6 => array (
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Adrenalinjunkie" 
                ),
                7 => array (
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Städtebummler" 
                ) 
        );

        $type [] = "";
        // Expenditure ranges
        $exp = explode ( ',', $_POST ['userBudget'] );
        foreach ( $exp as $key => $arrE ) {
            $arrEx = $arrE;
            if ($arrE < 300) {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .1;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .1;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .1;
            }
            if ($arrEx >= 300 && $arrEx <= 500) {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [6] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
            }
            if ($arrEx >= 600 && $arrEx <= 800) {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
            }
            if ($arrEx >= 900 && $arrEx <= 1000) {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
            }
            if ($arrEx >= 1500 && $arrEx <= 3000) {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
            }
        }

        // seasons
        $Season = explode ( ',', $_POST ['seasonString'] );
        foreach ( $Season as $key => $arrS ) {
            $arrSe = $arrS;
            if ($arrSe == "1") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .5;
            }
            if ($arrSe == "2") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .5;
            }
            if ($arrSe == "3") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .5;
            }
            if ($arrSe == "4") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .5;
            }
        }

        // user desires
        $desires = explode ( ',', $_POST ['desiresString'] );
        foreach ( $desires as $key => $arrD ) {
            $arrDe = $arrD;
            if ($arrDe == "1") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [1] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [6] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .2;
            }
            if ($arrDe == "2") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
            }
            if ($arrDe == "3") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .5;
            }
            if ($arrDe == "4") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
            }
            if ($arrDe == "5") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .8;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .8;
            }
            if ($arrDe == "6") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += 0;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .5;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .4;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .3;
            }
            if ($arrDe == "7") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .8;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [4] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [5] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .8;
                $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
            }
            if ($arrDe == "8") {
                $type [0] ["val"] += .8;
                $type [1] ["val"] += .3;
                $type [2] ["val"] += .9;
                $type [3] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
                $type [6] ["val"] += .7;
                $type [7] ["val"] += .3;
            }
        }

        // vacations period

        if ($period == "1") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .5;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .8;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .8;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .5;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .7;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .6;
        }
        if ($period == "2") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .8;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .8;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
        if ($period == "3") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
        if ($period == "4") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }

        // Vacation places
        if ($place == "1") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 0;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .7;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .7;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .7;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .5;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
        if ($place == "2") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .7;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .9;
        }
        if ($place == "3") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .9;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .8;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .9;
        }

        // Hotel Services

        if ($serv == "1") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .08;
        }
        if ($serv == "2") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .09;
        }
        if ($serv == "3") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }

        // Place Discoveries

        if ($disc == "1") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .05;
        }
        if ($disc == "2") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1.05;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }

        // Transportation
        if ($Trans == "1") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
        if ($Trans == "2") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .04;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .09;
        }
        if ($Trans == "3") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .08;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }

        // Hotel Ratting

        if ($stars == "1") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .05;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .05;
        }
        if ($stars == "2") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .06;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .06;
        }
        if ($stars == "3") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .07;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .07;
        }
        if ($stars == "4") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .09;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .09;
        }
        if ($stars == "5") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }

        // Traveling with Partner, Family or Alone
        if ($accomp == "1") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .19;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .19;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .18;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .19;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
        if ($accomp == "2") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .16;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .17;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .15;
        }
        if ($accomp == "3") {
            $type [0] ["val"] += .16;
            $type [1] ["val"] += .15;
            $type [2] ["val"] += .19;
            $type [3] ["val"] += .20;
            $type [4] ["val"] += .19;
            $type [5] ["val"] += .16;
            $type [6] ["val"] += .16;
            $type [7] ["val"] += .19;
        }

        // loop and count value Entered for Results outcome
        $maxVal = $type [0];
        for($i = 1; $i < count ( $type ); $i ++) {
            if ($type [$i] ["val"] > $maxVal ["val"]) {
                $maxVal = $type [$i];
            }
        }

        echo "<h3> Du bist " . $maxVal ["title"] . " </h3>";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the reason for tagging this question with Java ?

Comment: Use switch case, if php supports it

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik: Are you kidding? Of-course PHP supports it. One more thing tell me one popular language name which not support switch case ;-)

Comment: You can use switch case statements

Comment: I don't know that a `switch` would tidy up this code, make it easier to manage, or improve performance. My suggestion would be to store the various possible increments as an array and then use a function to test each condition and apply the correct increment.

Comment: @RaviHirani [tag:python]

Comment: @RoadieRich: Yes but there is a replacement with dictionary also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Hey are you sure that your code should need to have these lines

```
if ($arrEx >= 600 && $arrEx <= 800) {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
        if ($arrEx >= 900 && $arrEx <= 1000) {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
        if ($arrEx >= 1500 && $arrEx <= 3000) {
            $type [0] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [1] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [2] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [3] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [4] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [5] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [6] ["val"] += 1;
            $type [7] ["val"] += 1;
        }
```

you can store your ranges into array example Lower = {600, 900, 1500} and High = {800, 1000, 3000} and one 2D array which contain delta/increment which you need to increase now iterate loop and check on which index of array arrEx lie and update your type array's values i hope you understand (Sorry for my poor english).

EDITED--------------

I was saying is that suppose you have 2 one dimensional array $Lower = {L1, L2, L3.. Ln} and $High = {H1, H2, H3....Hn}  and one 2 dimensional array $increment = {{0_val_increment_value, 1_val_increment_value,,,,,7.}, ...... n times} now code will be

```
foreach ( $exp as $key => $arrE ) {
        $arrEx = $arrE;
        Loop: iterate n times using i {
                  low = $Lower[i] , high = $High[i]
                  IF arrEx lies in range THEN
                         Loop: iterate 8 times using j {
                                         $type[j]["val"] += increment[i][j] 
                        }
                   END IF
           }
   }
```

Above is pseudocode i think its easy to convert in php code :)

Comment: Hi Paras, i don't know which line you really mean. i just thought may the is way to minimise my if statement. and secound to reduice the rating filds name $type.

Comment: i don't know what do you mean by rating filds name. i have updated my answer if you still have problem then ask :) .

Comment: Thanks Paras i was lite busy so i couldnt check your Pseudocode. anyway thanx will get back to you if anything

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch case` instead of so many `else if` statements

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp